# Android ble, requestConnectionPriority not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to send 10 bytes of data, every 30milisecond,s between 2 android devices using bluetooth low enegry notifications. The goal is to achieve low latency communication and there is no interest in low energy.

You can check the results in the [Delay graph(Y field = delta time between packets)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nffK0.png). The first 10seconds the communication is being perfomed good enough. (The interval between the packets is max 30-40ms). However after the 10th second, the intervals are either extremly high or extremely low.

This is probably happenning due to non strict connection interval parameters. You can check a sample of [hci_events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBzJu.png) that shows clearly the slow down is caused by the hci_events.

I have tried to configure the parameters of the connection, calling from the master the function

```
requestConnectionPriority
```

However, it didn't change anything on the result graph. I also check the packets using wireshark and findout that the master didn't even send a request for configuring the connection interval. I also tried another configuration request with

```
requestMtu
```

with exactly the same results, no update packets was send from the master.

So, there are 2 questions that show up from this observations.

- Has ble a timeout in the 10th second in order to ensure low energy consumption? If so, how can I disable it?
- Is some thing wrong calling requestConnectionPriority, from the android 6.0.1 with the role of the central(master)? Can you give me a simple example on how is being called properly?

Note that `requestConnectionPriority`  is called right after the connection being establish in the `onConnectionStateChange` of the `BluetoothGattCallback`.

The device that has role of a slave(server) is running (Android 5.1.1) and the master(client) is running (Android 6.0.1).

Thanks a lot!

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** It's crucial to mention the **way the connection is being initiated** between the devices.

- The central device calls `device.connectGatt`, where device is `BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address)`. Address is a hardcoded string, the peripheral's **public mac address**. You can check [logcat logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFCuN.png) and also [hci logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DgQ3Cgngl1DPzd2nFfMUbPpRfSSUd_fr).
- I have also tried connecting with the legit method (peripheral **advertising** and connect to **scanned random address**), but I get an error 'initiate direct connection fail, topology limitation'. You can check [logcat  logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVgvH.png) and also [hci logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13MzyUnfWKUT0pBquyu1dQh6ZmySWtvmi).

Answer (score 1):

> Has ble a timeout in the 10th second in order to ensure low energy consumption? If so, how can I disable it?

No

> Is some thing wrong calling requestConnectionPriority, from the android 6.0.1 with the role of the central(master)? Can you give me a simple example on how is being called properly?

I'm not aware of any bugs regarding requestConnectionPriority. But you could try to execute that method after the onServicesDiscovered callback. Android temporarily changes connection interval to 7.5 ms during the GATT service discovery so it might be confused if you don't wait until the service discovery is completed.

Regarding requestMtu, make sure you execute that method while there are no other GATT operations pending (otherwise it won't work).

One additional tip is to use an air sniffer and not only look at the hci logs.

Comment: Thank you Emil for your prompt reply. I tested your recommendation, but it didn't resulted in different behaviour. Maybe the problem the way I am initiating the connection. I will update the question in the next minutes.

Comment: I'd like to see your HCI log. The logcat log tells that connection parameter update failed, which doesn't seem so good. The "topology" limitation means that your Bluetooth chip doesn't support initiating a connection at the same time it does something else (maybe connectable advertising or slave connection?). What Android device do you have?

Comment: I've just updated the question adding the hci logs. Specifically, for central we based on this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt) and for the peripheral this [example](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver) which was working on Samsung S7 as peripheral and Sony M5 as central. Our problem occurs when we use as a central [Orbbec Pessec device](https://orbbec3d.com/product-persee/), which has API 21(higher stats from M5) and bluetooth 4.0 with COD COMPUTER. Thank you a lot and excuse me for the delay but I hadn’t enable the notifications.

Comment: From your first hci log, you don't actually run GATT over BLE. You run GATT over Bluetooth classic. That's why you can't update connection parameters since that is a BLE thing. The bluetooth chip seems to be a crappy one since it doesn't support multiple states simultaneously (except advertising and scanning at the same time). See the LE Read Supported States packet. For example it's not allowed to have a scan at the same time you have a connection or initiating a connection. Therefore you get the "topology" error.

Comment: Hello Emil!
The bluetooth chip is this one [AP6212](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/images/5/57/AP6212_V1.1_09022014.pdf).
I also changed the client's (central) OS from android to linux, ubuntu 16.04 and using `hcitool lescan` and `gatttool -t random -b [scanned address] -I` and then `connect`, I succesfully connected with the same peripheral and the lescan operation was automatiically cancelled.

So probably the problem is somewhere on the andorid connectGatt java class for the supported states of this chip. Do you have any  recommendation on how can I overcome that issue on android?